# modify model's parameters in dymola's script file

Tags: modelica, dymola

I am trying to use a .mos file in Dymola to do multiple simulations, here is an example from [claytex's blog](https://www.claytex.com/blog/how-to-simulate-a-model-multiple-times-with-different-parameter-values/):

```
openModel("C:/Dymola/Testing/Test1.mo")
translateModel ("Test1");
for i in 1:10 loop
         a=i;
         simulate();
         system("copy dsres.mat results"+String(i) +".mat");
end for;
```

It seems when I translate a model in the script file, I could modify the model's parameters again, which is different when I use Dymola's GUI. In Dymola's GUI, if I try to modify the parameter after I translate the model, I have to re-translate the model. My question is:
In Dymola's script file, when I modify the parameter, how does Dymola deal with it?

Comment: Modifying a parameter using a script is equivalent to modifying a parameter in the Dymola GUI variable browser.  See section 1.2 of the Dymola User Manual volume 1A.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The above comment by "user2024223" is correct, but I think "variable browser" is not stressed enough and some more explanation could help:

When changing the model's parameters after translation, make sure you are **not** using the model editing (either "Graphical" or "Text"-Ribbon), because this will change the model's code and therefore (usually) force re-translation. The same is true for the "Model View" in the "Simulation" Ribbon.

The code will not be changed if you use the "Variable Browser" in the "Simulation"-Ribbon. An alternative (which actually does the same) is typing the parameter value in the "Commands"-line. E.g. this could be `J1.J=5` for the `CoupledClutches` example. Both of the variants in the paragraph should behave similarly to the script.

Answer (score 3):

Dymola deals with parameter changes after translation by modifying the dsin.txt file.
Some/many parameters have been evaluated and cannot be changed in this way - these variables are not editable in the Variable Browser.

You will get a warning if you try to change non-editable variables in a script.

**Note**: You should in most cases not have to deal with re-translating the model even after modifying the editable parameters *of that model* in the GUI. Just simulate the model again - hopefully it does not need re-translation.